# Create-react-app with codesplitting and await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

In [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/05/18/whats-new-in-create-react-app.html#code-splitting-with-dynamic-import) article on official `react` website, I can clearly see that using `await` to dynamically import the module is allowed, yet when I try to do it (exactly like in the example) in my code an error is what I get:

```
Syntax error: await is a reserved word (11:31)
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Code just for convenience:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        lazyComponent: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { default: Message } = await import('./Message.js');
        this.setState({
            lazyComponent: <Message />
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p>Let's start!</p>
                {this.state.lazyComponent || <p>Loading...</p> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Goerge - it is practically a copy of what is showed in the link.

Comment: "practically", that's the point

Comment: await requires async

Answer (score 6):

You missed the `async` word before `componentDidMount()`, it is shown in the link you provided

Comment: Omg. Embarassing as hell.

Comment: @Ancinek this is why it's better to post the code with the question, that way we can see if it's a simple mistake or not, It happens to everyone at some point so I wouldn't feel too bad :)

Comment: Actually I had the same problem, don't be embarrassed, this question saved me minutes if not longer...